# Improving search speed in web application with sql

Tags: c#, sql, search

I have a .NET web app that has a SQL back end containing many tables.

I have a working "global" search function that uses a SQL View to union all my tables giving my c# app something to search against.

e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW vSearch AS
SELECT field1 as SearchText
FROM Table1
UNTION
SELECT field2 as SearchText
FROM Table2
UNTION
SELECT field3 as SearchText
FROM Table3
```

Then in my c# I can use something like

```
var results = ctx.vSearch.Where(w => w.SearchText.Contains(SearchTerm));
```

This is working fine but my problem is that it is very slow.

Before I look at trying to improve performance am I on the right track with this method or is there a better way to do a global search across multiple tables. Am I missing an "industry standard" way of searching across multiple tables?

Comment: Perhaps you can use `UNION ALL` instead? (Duplicate elimination costs.)

Comment: jarlh thank you, I didn't know about UNION ALL, that has increased the speed of my view by about 5 times!

Comment: Great to hear! Note that you may get duplicates with UNION ALL.

Comment: It depends on what technology you use (SQL). Is it MySQL, Postgres, Microsoft SQL Server, etc.  How much data are we talking about?  Does it support indexed views? Does it support full-text indexing? If so, that's where you will gain a lot of performance, closer to the data.

Comment: The industry standard is to write a customized query per table, utilizing the correct indexes (you do have indexes?). Do not try to filter against a unioned view, it generally performs badly. For further help, we need to see index and table definitions, and please share a query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: If you are doing wildcard prefix searches (`Contains` rather than `StartsWith`), you are alway going to have bad performance because indexes cannot be used. Perhaps you need Full-Text Search. A trigram "index" may be an option, see https://sqlperformance.com/2017/09/sql-performance/sql-server-trigram-wildcard-search